# Trying to start DataFrame headers at the beginning of the columns when reading a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean up some data from a csv where '|'s are delimiters (yet they also occur in some of the fields). I am using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|')
```

As result, I end with more columns than there are headers, that I need to clean up.

How do I push the headers to the beginning of the columns? Every time I read the DataFrame, all the headers are pushed to the right.

Comment: Can you show an example of your data?  If `|` is a delimiter but also occurs in the data that is a problem unless there's some kind of escaping.

Comment: @BrenBarn I don't think I am allowed to. That being said, you are correct - it is a problem. So I am trying to fix this (and I already have an approach in mind). I want to shift the headers over so that when I remove data in each of the columns, the headers will line up with the appropriate columns.

Comment: It's going to be hard to tell you how to manipulate the data without seeing an example of the problem.

Comment: @Matthew, can you produce a dummy example that reproduces your problem?
You can `from io import StringIO` and use something like `file_contents = "your|columns|go|here\n|your|data|goes|here\n"`  `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_contents), delimiter='|')`

Comment: This way it will be easy for us to reproduce your problem and give suggestions to fix it.

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(fn1, delimiter='|')
print(df)`

Comment: Sure, thanks. Here's the dummy file I've been using:

`file_contents = 'testing | will this work\n idk | we will see | probably not | what is going on???\n last try | ok'`

Comment: What do you hope to get from that input?  pandas is for *tabular* data.  If your data does not have the same number of items in every row then it is not tabular.